# How can I solve this error with transcribe?

Tags: ee2, solspace, solspace-calendar, calendar, transcribe

I have been trying to implement a calendar by using the calendar module by solspace, but I keep getting this error that says:

"The query you submitted is not valid.
Filename: third_party/transcribe/ext.transcribe.php"

I'm not sure whether the problem is caused by transcribe or the calendar module.

Here is my tag code below:

```
  {exp:calendar:cal
      {if segment_3 == "by_calendar"}
         {if segment_5 == ''}calendar_name="{segment_4}" date_range_start="year-month-01" date_range_end="year-month-last"{/if}
         {if segment_5 != ''}calendar_name="{segment_4}" date_range_start="{segment_5}-{segment_6}-01" date_range_end="{segment_5}-{segment_6}-last"{/if}
      {/if}
      {if segment_3 != "by_calendar"}
         {if segment_3 == ''}date_range_start="year-month-01" date_range_end="year-month-last"{/if}
         {if segment_3 != ""}date_range_start="{segment_3}-{segment_4}-01" date_range_end="{segment_3}-{segment_4}-last"{/if}
      {/if}
   }
```

Comment: At least for Calendar, the little code present in the opening question looks fine. The error mentioning Transcribe might be a hint to look into Transcribe. Try simplifying and isolating the code as much as possible until you're left with the minimum to trigger the error. That can help isolate your issue. Good advice for any template/parsing-based issues.

Comment: I deleted transcribe, but I still seem to have some problems with the calendar module. I created a calendar channel field in one of my channels, and when I try to publish an event I just get the name of the channel field, but there is nothing beneath it. I also tried to delete the module and install it again, but that didn't work.

Comment: "_I created a calendar channel field in one of my channels_". You can't do that. You **must** use the channels and custom field groups provided by Calendar when installed. If you are trying to reinstall, make sure the old channel/custom field groups are removed first.